# Gatsby with External 8base data

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to create dynamic pages using 8base data. I have a site with Carbon Design Theme that uses .mdx pages.

- What is the best way to create these pages: via gatsby-node.js createPage with GraphQL layer, or directly on .mdx pages via Apollo Query with dynamic parameter?
- I have the connection with 8base established, and I'm able to pull the data on the page.  However, I don't see the data in the GraphQL layer.  Do I need to add a plugin in a gatsby-config file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend following [this doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-graphql/) for setting up and using a GraphQL source for your Gatsby project. The GraphQL API 8base is producing doesn't require any specific plugin other than a GraphQL source.

Once you install `npm install gatsby-graphql-source` you can then make the plugin declaration in your gatsby-config.js.

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        typeName: "8base",
        fieldName: "eightbase",
        url: "https://api.8base.com/" + YOUR_8BASE_WORKSPACE_ID,
        // However you plan on setting your auth header, you can do it here.
        headers: async () => {
          return {
            Authorization: await getAuthorizationToken(),
          }
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```